# React redux do not sync props in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I am using React redux with firebase realtime database.
In App.js I am dispatching an action `fetchAllPosts`

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAllPosts();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          // something ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      fetchAllPosts: () => {dispatch(allPosts())}
  }
}
```

My action looks like this (I am using redux-thunk):

**action**

```
export function allPosts() {
    return (dispatch) => {  
firebase.database().ref('posts/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        dispatch({type: "ALL_POSTS", postsArray: snapshot.val(), loading: false})
    })
    }
}
```

Then I am combining reducers (I know in this case it is not necessary):

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    allPosts: postsReducer
})
```

My reducer looks like this:

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    allPosts: []
}

const postsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ALL_POSTS" :
        console.log("action payload all posts", action.postsArray)
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            allPosts: action.postsArray
        }
        break;
        default:
        return state
    }
    return state
}
```

And finally: my SinglePostview component looks like this:
**SinglePostview.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class SinglePostview extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log("ppp", this.props)
        return (
            <h2>{this.props.post.title}</h2>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownprops) => {
    const postId = ownprops.match.params.postid
    return {
        post: state.allPosts.allPosts[postId]
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SinglePostview);
```

Here when the render method is executing, `this.props.post` is undefined and I have the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

The problem is: when the app loads for the first time, `props.post` is undefined (so I have an error) and after about 1 second it receives the value but it doesn't change anything - the error still exists and the value is not displaying.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: can you comment out `<h2>{this.props.post.title}</h2>` and maybe return `null` and see if your `console.log` statement ever picks the value from redux store

Comment: it takes the value from redux store finally, but when rednder executes it do not has the value yet.

Comment: check my answer, if every other part is fine, means you should try to confirm `post` is not undefined first

Comment: That being said, `post: state.allPosts.allPosts[postId]` are you sure of this?
`allPosts` seems to be an array. unless it is an object (in which case, change the `initialState` to something like: `{}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your reducer is fine, you can fix this by

changing this

```
render() {
        return (
            <h2>{this.props.post.title}</h2>
        )
    }
```

To this:

```
render() {
        if (!this.props.post){
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <h2>{this.props.post.title}</h2>
        )
    }
```

or

```
render() {
        return (
            <h2>{this.props.post && this.props.post.title}</h2>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining allPosts to be an array

```
    const initialState = {
    allPosts: []
    }
```

But you are trying to access it like an object.

```
state.allPosts.allPosts[postId]
```

Hence, if your state.allPosts.allPosts is an array , try using the ES6 find() method to get a post from the array with the postId.

Assuming

```
state.allPosts.allPosts = [
   {postId: 1,title:'abcd'},
   {postId:2,title:'def'}
]
 state.allPosts.allPosts.find(post => postId === post.postId)
```